# Apache Commons CLI - print trailing args in help output

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I'm using Apache Commons CLI 1.2 to parse a command line that takes options and extra arguments at the end. Ex: `mycmd -d DIR extra stuff`

I know how to get 'extra' and 'stuff' using `CommandLine.getArgs()`, but I don't know how to display those extra arguments in my help output. When I make a call like this:

```
new HelpFormatter().printHelp("mycmd", opts, true);
```

I get output like:

```
usage: mycmd -d DIR
```

without the extra arguments. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is so lame that trailing args cannot be defined as part of apache-commons-cli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only way to display those extra arguments would be to not print the automatically generated usage statement and instead print a custom usage statement like this:

```
new HelpFormatter().printHelp("mycmd -d <DIR> extra stuff", opts);
```

or this

```
new HelpFormatter().printHelp("mycmd [options] extra stuff", opts);
```

or however you want to format your usage statement.

Comment: Thanks. I previously tried your second example with a third argument of 'true', but that displayed the arguments after 'extra stuff', which looked weird. I ended up using a variation of example 2, but with a header: `new HelpFormatter().printHelp("mycmd [OPTIONS] extra stuff", "Where OPTIONS can be:", opts, null)`.