# How to define trailing args as part of the options?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I'd like to parse a command of the following format: `mycmd source dest`.

If the source or dest isn't found, I'd like the parser to fail. How can I define trailing args as part of the options using [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)?

I couldn't find a way to do it. I have a feeling this cannot be done. If the trailing args could be defined, I wouldn't have needed to add them manually to the help - as stated in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871711/435605).

Comment: The question you linked to contains the mechanism to retrieve the extra arguments. Use [CommandLine.getArgs()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgs%28%29).

Comment: I'm looking for more than a way to get the trailing args. I'm looking for a way to parse them like any other option. For example, if an option has an argument but the argument is missing the parsing will fail. I'm looking to do the same with the trailing args.

Comment: If those "trailing args" have a meaning (different meaning), why not give them an option? Why not use `mycmd -s source -d dest`? As far as I can see, trailing args are used for args of the same type. Ant - for example - uses them to let the user specify several targets.

Comment: Then, for example, there can be several sources - at least one. I don't want to complicate the question.

Answer (score 1):

Commons-cli does not support special handling of the trailing arguments currently. You need to parse the trailing arguments yourself for now, i.e. with something like this:

```
    String[] trailing = cmdLine.getArgs();
    if(trailing.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need at least 3 arguments <src> [<src> ...] <dest>");
    }
    String dest = trailing[trailing.length-1];
    String[] sources = Arrays.copyOf(trailing, trailing.length-1);
```